# Invalid thumbnail URL when uploading a video on dailymotion api

Tags: dailymotion-api

I use dailymotion api to upload video : https://api.dailymotion.com/me/videos
In most of the cases, it works well. But sometimes, I have this error :
{"error":{"more_info":"https://developer.dailymotion.com/api#error-codes","code":400,"message":"Invalid thumbnail URL","type":"invalid_parameter"}}

When I upload the video again with the same parameters, it works.

here is a piece of my C# code :

```
    var dico = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    dico.Add("access_token", accessToken);
    dico.Add("url", config.Url);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(config.ThumbnailUrl))
       dico.Add("thumbnail_url", config.ThumbnailUrl);
    var postContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(dico);

    var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("https://api.dailymotion.com/me/videos", postContent);
```

I Cannot give the thumbnail URL but it contains 287 characters. Is it a problem? Do I need to URL encode ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

URL of this video's raw thumbnail (full size respecting ratio).
Some users have the permission to change this value by providing an URL to a custom thumbnail. If you don't have the permission, the thumbnail won't be updated. Note: for live streams, the thumbnail is automatically generated every 5 mn by default; it is not possible anymore to manually refresh the preview.